# Use autolayout to position view on home button's side

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to use auto layout to position a view on the Home button's side of the device, independent from it's orientation.

My question is, can this be achieved through auto layout? And if yes, how?

Comment: You can add constraints to the view and enable / disable the appropriate ones whenever the device rotates. I don't think there is a pure interface builder way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't if you are supporting more than one orientation. You can add add the view to desired position using code and change the frame in `viewWillTransitionToSize`.